# Issue with broadcast Join in Spark 1.6.0

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark creates different SQL execution plans in versions **1.5.2** and **1.6.0**.

The database contains one large facts table (*f*) and several small dimension tables (*d1, d2*).

The dimension tables (*d1, d2*) are cached in Spark using:

```
sqlContext.cacheTable("d1");
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from d1").count();

sqlContext.cacheTable("d2");
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from d2").count();
```

The size of tables *d1* and *d2*: *~100MB* (the tab *STORAGE* shows this size for the tables in *Spark Web UI*).

The Spark SQL is configured by the broadcast parameter (1GB) which is more  than the size of the tables:

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=1048576000
```

The SQL is:

```
SELECT d1.name, d2.name, SUM(f.clicks) 
FROM f 
    JOIN d1 on f.d1_id = d1.id 
    JOIN d2 on f.d2_id = d2.id
WHERE d1.name='A' AND f.date=20160101
GROUP BY d1.name, d2.name
ORDER BY SUM(f.clicks) DESC
```

The query is executed using *ThriftServer*.

When we run this query using Spark **1.5.2** the query is executed fast and the execution plan contains ***BroadcastJoin*** wth dimensions.

But when we run the same query  using Spark **1.6.0** the query is executed very slow and the execution plan contains ***SortMergeJoin*** with dimensions.

The environment for both executions is the same (the same *Yarn Cluster*).
Provided executors count, tasks count per executor and memory of the executors are the same for both executions.

What can I do to configure Spark 1.6.0 for using BroadcastJoin in sql executions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Spark 1.6.1? Also, could you post the execution plan from "explain {your query}"?

Comment: Did you found any solution for the 1.6.0 version of spark for broadcast join?